# jQuery Ajax success function returns null?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I use the following the jquery statements to call my php controller function, it gets called but my result is not returned to my success function....

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/codeigniter_cup_myth/stylesheets/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/codeigniter_cup_myth/stylesheets/calendar.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/codeigniter_cup_myth/stylesheets/date_picker.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/codeigniter_cup_myth/javascript/jquery1.4.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/codeigniter_cup_myth/javascript/jquery.pagination.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                getRecordspage();
            });

            function getRecordspage() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:"http://localhost/codeigniter_cup_myth/index.php/adminController/mainAccount",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    global:false,
                    async: true,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(result) {
                        alert(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table  id="chkbox" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" width="100%" class="table_Style_Border">
            <tr>
                <td class="grid_header" align="center">S.No</td>
                <td class="grid_header" align="center">Account Name</td>
                <td class="grid_header" align="center">Account Acronym</td>
                <td class="grid_header" align="center">Finance Year Start</td>
                <td class="grid_header" align="center">Finance Year End</td>
                <td class="grid_header" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr> <td colspan="5"> </td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

My controller method,

```
function mainAccount()
{
    $_SESSION['menu'] = 'finance';
    $data['account'] = $this->adminmodel->getaccountDetails();
    if(empty($data['account']))
    {
        $data['comment'] = 'No record found !';
    }
    $json = json_encode($data);
    return $json;
}
```

I get the `alert(1);` in my success function but my `alert(result);` show `null`. How do I fix this problem?

This was what I got when I gave `print_r($data);`:

```
Array ( [account] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [dAcc_id] => 1 [dAccountName] => Govt. College Of Technology [dAccountAcronym] => GCT [dFromDate] => 2010-04-02 [dToDate] => 2011-05-03 ) [1] => Array ( [dAcc_id] => 3 [dAccountName] => sample4 [dAccountAcronym] => smp_4 [dFromDate] => 2010-03-17 [dToDate] => 2011-03-03 ) [2] => Array ( [dAcc_id] => 4 [dAccountName] => sample3 [dAccountAcronym] => smp_3 [dFromDate] => 2010-03-16 [dToDate] => 2011-03-17 ) [3] => Array ( [dAcc_id] => 5 [dAccountName] => sample5 [dAccountAcronym] => smp_5 [dFromDate] => 2010-03-12 [dToDate] => 2011-03-03 ) [4] => Array ( [dAcc_id] => 6 [dAccountName] => sample2 [dAccountAcronym] => smp2 [dFromDate] => 2010-03-01 [dToDate] => 2011-03-16 ) [5] => Array ( [dAcc_id] => 7 [dAccountName] => sample1 [dAccountAcronym] => smp_1 [dFromDate] => 2010-03-11 [dToDate] => 2011-03-03 ) [6] => Array ( [dAcc_id] => 8 [dAccountName] => ss [dAccountAcronym] => ss [dFromDate] => 2010-04-04 [dToDate] => 2010-04-06 ) ) )
```

When I did `print_r(json_encode($data['account']));`, I got this:

```
[{"dAcc_id":"1","dAccountName":"Govt. College Of Technology","dAccountAcronym":"GCT","dFromDate":"2010-04-02","dToDate":"2011-05-03"},{"dAcc_id":"3","dAccountName":"sample4","dAccountAcronym":"smp_4","dFromDate":"2010-03-17","dToDate":"2011-03-03"},{"dAcc_id":"4","dAccountName":"sample3","dAccountAcronym":"smp_3","dFromDate":"2010-03-16","dToDate":"2011-03-17"},{"dAcc_id":"5","dAccountName":"sample5","dAccountAcronym":"smp_5","dFromDate":"2010-03-12","dToDate":"2011-03-03"},{"dAcc_id":"6","dAccountName":"sample2","dAccountAcronym":"smp2","dFromDate":"2010-03-01","dToDate":"2011-03-16"},{"dAcc_id":"7","dAccountName":"sample1","dAccountAcronym":"smp_1","dFromDate":"2010-03-11","dToDate":"2011-03-03"},{"dAcc_id":"8","dAccountName":"ss","dAccountAcronym":"ss","dFromDate":"2010-04-04","dToDate":"2010-04-06"}]
```

Comment: The result body *can* be `null` and still be a valid result if the header is `200 OK`. Have you checked your URL actually returns something?

Comment: @pekka i inspected through firebug my response tab had nothing....

Comment: @pekka my post had this `JSON
  
Source
{}`

Comment: @udaya then the response is empty, and the `null` appears correctly - strange because in your code, that can't really happen.

Comment: @pekka any suggesstion how it can be done?

Comment: @udaya you would have to debug your PHP script step by step and look at which point the data gets lost. Plus, activate error reporting.

Comment: @pekka i ll do it immediately...

Comment: @pekka i do have my `print_r` shows json string... But `return` keyword doesn't seem to work right for me....

Comment: My guess would be you are trying to JSON encode either faulty data, or a string that is already JSON encoded. In such cases, json_encode() returns null. Can you show the actual data please?

Comment: @udaya strange, looks okay. Can you show `print_r(json_encode($data))`?

Comment: Oh and how do you call the main controller function? Can you post the body of the full PHP script?

Comment: @pekka i ll edit it for you...

Comment: @Pekka see my edit i want to get the json result and iterate a table using jquery in my success function....

Comment: @udaya The json array looks okay. I don't know enough about CI to be able to tell why the returned value is not output, sorry.

Comment: @pekka  Its ok yaar thanks for your effort..
I will check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set the content type correct?

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

With CodeIgniter, are you meant to return the JSON object or output it? If there's no view associated with the method then nothing will be output. Try, just to see if it works:

```
$_SESSION['menu'] = 'finance';
$data['account'] = $this->adminmodel->getaccountDetails();
if (empty($data['account'])) {
  $data['comment'] = 'No record found !';
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

Lastly, verify the URL you are going to and see if it returns something.

Take a look at [JSON Helper](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/JSON_Helper/).

Comment: @cletus when i `print_r(json_encode($data));` i get the json string but why can't return it to my ajax success function...

Comment: @udaya - what @cletus is saying is, try `echo json_encode($data);` instead of `return $data`;

Answer (score 2):

The most common reason this happens is if you are a non-secure page trying to communicate via ajax with a secure page, or vise versa (i.e. http ajaxing https)